# Git: Use two branches with same name from different remotes

Tags: git, branch, git-branch, git-remote

I'm using a repository which exists both on github and on an internal gitlab.
I have set up two remotes: `origin` (github) and `gitlab`.

**How can I easily interact with the branch `master` of both remotes?**

What I've tried:

1. `git checkout --track gitlab/master` -> error: `A branch named 'master' already exists.`
2. `git checkout -b master-gitlab --track gitlab/master` -> worked, I now have a local branch `master-gitlab` and the console output tells me: `master-gitlab set up to track remote branch master from gitlab.` -> perfect, this is what I want!
3. `git push gitlab master-gitlab` -> this creates a **new remote branch** `master-gitlab` on remote `gitlab` which is **not what I want** and inconsistent with the output of the last command.
4. I can now do `git push gitlab master-gitlab:master` which pushes `master-gitlab` to `master` of the remote `gitlab`. But I always forget how to do this and it's not very intuitive.

**Is there an easier way to track the `master` branch of a different remote and push to it?**

**Is this a git-bug that it first (3) is telling me tracking `master` and afterwards creating a new branch on push?**

Comment: At your 3rd point, I guess you meant it creates a new remote branch called **master-gitlab**?

Comment: yes, thanks, I've changed it.

Comment: For #3, i believe you want to `git push --set-upstream gitlab master`, which should set it permanently.    (sorry for necro-bump, i was searching the subject.)

Comment: I don't think that this is what I wanted, since it would push my local branch "master" (linked with github) to gitlab. What I wanted to have is two different local branches "master" (github) and "master-gitlab" containing different states of my project, one linked with github, the other with gitlab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a bug in the sense that git is doing what the documentation says it will do.  It also may not be the most intuitive result in this case, but with how many different ways there are to relate remote branches to local refs I don't really think there is a behavior that will be intuitive to everyone in every situation.

In general, push configuration is set separately from pull configuration.  (You can see the `git push` documentation for a rundown of how it tries to figure out what to push where when you don't specify everything on the command line.  https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push)

That said, the *default* push configuration does try to use the pull configuration **if** you are pushing to the default remote.  You can configure `push` to always default to upstream configuration with

```
git config push.default upstream
```

Then you can push `master-gitlab` using just

```
git push
```

if it's checked out, and

```
git push gitlab master-gitlab
```

in any case.  Of course since this changes a default setting, it could potentially affect your other interactions with gitlab, so I'd encourage you to review the docs and make sure you understand the differences in behavior to decide if it's worth it.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'm not a fan of changing the default properties because it means that my commands and workflow possibly won't work on an other machine. So in which situation the default configuration makes more sense? To my mind it's simply inconsistent and confusing that push creates a new remote branch if git before told me that my local branch is tracking `master` of the remote.

Comment: @klues - Well, just to put this conversation in perspective, the software does what it does; neither of us wrote git, and neither of us will rewrite it, so it doesn't really matter whether we are convinced that the defaults make sense or not.  But to answer to the best of my understanding, the defaults are meant to be "safe" (not necessarily 'most useful") to beginners, and the expectation is that people who understand their use cases better will change the setting if appropriate.