# How can I work with multiple remote repositories in Git if they contain a branch with the same name but different data?

Tags: github

I'm using a repository (github.com/gravitystorm), a fork of this repository (github.com/giggls) and my own fork (github.com/astridx).

This is my setup.

```
/$ git remote -v
astridx https://github.com/astridx/openstreetmap-carto-de.git (fetch)
astridx https://github.com/astridx/openstreetmap-carto-de.git (push)
giggls  https://github.com/giggls/openstreetmap-carto-de.git (fetch)
giggls  https://github.com/giggls/openstreetmap-carto-de.git (push)
origin  https://github.com/gravitystorm/openstreetmap-carto.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/gravitystorm/openstreetmap-carto.git (push)
```

In the two remote repositories (gravitystorm, giggls), which I can not change, there is a branch called `master` - but both `master`-branches contain different data. I would like to work with both master branches.

**I have done so far:**

- I have `cloned` the master from `github.com/gravitystorm/openstreetmap-carto.git`.
- Then I run `git pull giggls master`. This led to many conflicts. Besides, I do not want to `pull`. I want the original master branch on giggls

```
    $ git pull giggls master 
    From https://github.com/giggls/openstreetmap-carto-de
     * branch              master     -> FETCH_HEAD
    Auto-merging water.mss
    Auto-merging style.mss
    CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in style.mss
    Auto-merging project.mml
    Auto-merging CHANGELOG.md
    CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in CHANGELOG.md
    Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

- Then I thought that the fetch command is a solution. Because it does no merge. But my data does also not change.

```
$ git fetch giggls master
From https://github.com/giggls/openstreetmap-carto-de
 * branch              master     -> FETCH_HEAD
```

The only solution that occurs to me is that I name the branches differently on my machine. Here are the commands that I use for this:

```
$ git branch giggls_master

$ git checkout giggls_master
Switched to branch 'giggls_master'

$ git pull giggls masterFrom https://github.com/giggls/openstreetmap-carto-de
 * branch              master     -> FETCH_HEAD
CONFLICT ...

$ git fetch giggls 
remote: Enumerating objects: 5, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (5/5), done.
remote: Total 7 (delta 5), reused 5 (delta 5), pack-reused 2
Unpacking objects: 100% (7/7), done.
...

$ git reset --hard giggls/master
HEAD is now at 2f8c9d19 GERMAN STYLE: Render localized railway station names in addition to local names
```

**Is there really no better solution? One in which the branch is not just `master` but `giggls/master`, for example.**

I saw this this question: [Git: Use two branches with same name from different remotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58080762/git-use-two-branches-with-same-name-from-different-remotes) 
In my opinion, this is another problem. The data in the master branch is not different. There are two branches at different providers (gihub, gitlab)

Comment: How are you working with the two remotes? Are you trying to get new commits that are in both the original repo and the fork and merge them into your own fork?  If so, then `pull` is usually what you would do and any conflicts would have to be resolved -by either manually doing it or possibly through a simple rebase with no need to merge things. Also, take a look at [git-worktree](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree) and let me know if it sounds like it could be a solution for your case.

Comment: I would like to always have the current levels of the two remotes on my machine for testing and possibly contribute to both. I would often pull both of them. My contributions are not the problem. For this I would create a new branch and push it.
I do not know x. I will take a look at it. Many thanks.

Comment: It sounds like git-worktree might be the answer for you then. Just add both remotes and create a worktree for each master. You can then have each master available as a separate worktree, you would just have to change into the respective directories to manage things and run git commands for the respective branches.

Comment: I recieved a notification on this question. I forgot about my comments. Rereading your question, while git-woktree could work, just cloning each separate repoistory would work. Though, you could also just make a pull request from the fork and the original upstream into your own fork under a new branch so that your own fork will now contain two new branches containing code from giggles and gravity storm. Then you could use git-worktree to work with them in their own unique directories. Then you can just add the respective upstream remotes, giggles and gravity to keep things updated if you want.